# Make error: ffbuild/config.mak(1) : fatal error U1034: syntax error : separator missing Stop

Tags: c, windows, ffmpeg, makefile

Im trying to build ffmpeg on windows but I am getting the error in the title when i use nmake. What is causing this?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images to SO overflow; please cut and paste the text instead.  This makefile doesn't look like a legal `nmake` makefile to me; I don't think `nmake` supports the `ifndef` operator.  This looks more like a GNU make makefile.

Comment: sorry, I posted an image so you could see all the symbols

Comment: Also this image isnt of the makefile. its of config.mak, the file which supposedly has the issue when i run 'nmake -f Makefile'

Comment: Images mean (a) no one can find this question if they search for that text, and (b) we can't cut and paste parts of the example into an answer, we have to retype it by hand.  In any event, as I said above, this isn't an `nmake` makefile so you can't use it with `nmake`.